# Could not convert string to float on NaiveBayes Spark example

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm following [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/mllib-naive-bayes.html) tutorial on Spark 1.6.

I've copy the same code as follow:

```
from pyspark.mllib.classification import NaiveBayes, NaiveBayesModel
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf


def parseLine(line):
    parts = line.split(',')
    label = float(parts[0])
    features = Vectors.dense([float(x) for x in parts[1].split(' ')])
    return LabeledPoint(label, features)

conf= SparkConf()
conf.setAppName("NaiveBaye")
conf.set('spark.driver.memory','6g')
conf.set('spark.executor.memory','6g')
conf.set('spark.cores.max',156)

sc = SparkContext(conf= conf)

data = sc.textFile('sample_naive_bayes_data.txt').map(parseLine)

# Split data aproximately into training (60%) and test (40%)
training, test = data.randomSplit([0.6, 0.4], seed=0)

# Train a naive Bayes model.
model = NaiveBayes.train(training, 1.0)

# Make prediction and test accuracy.
predictionAndLabel = test.map(lambda p: (model.predict(p.features), p.label))
accuracy = 1.0 * predictionAndLabel.filter(lambda (x, v): x == v).count() / test.count()

# Save and load model
model.save(sc, "model")
sameModel = NaiveBayesModel.load(sc, "model")
```

sample_naive_bayes_data.txt contain this:

```
0, 1.0 0.0 0.0
0, 2.0 0.0 0.0
1, 0.0 1.0 0.0
1, 0.0 2.0 0.0
2, 0.0 0.0 1.0
2, 0.0 0.0 2.0
```

This is a very basic tutorial but still not working.

It give me this error: could not convert string to float on this line:

```
features = Vectors.dense([float(x) for x in parts[1].split(' ')])
```

Can anyone explain me why and how fix it?

### Edit 1

I'm trying some changes to work with string values:

```
label = str(parts[0])
features = Vectors.dense([str(x) for x in parts[1].split('')])
```

and with this dataset:

```
positive, happy food food
positive, dog food food
negative, food happy food
negative, food dog food
neutral, food food happy
neutral, food food dog
```

There are the same values but with string instead of float values. 
In the previous example accuracy was: 1.0.

Now if I try to run this code I receive this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: happy on this line: 
model = NaiveBayes.train(training, 1.0)
```

Comment: Might help find the issue if you print x before that line. Then you can see what is in x when it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because of **`split(" ")`**. The space in sample_naive_bayes_data.txt and the space in the split method is not matching.

**replace**

```
features = Vectors.dense([float(x) for x in parts[1].split(' ')])
```

**with**

```
features = Vectors.dense([float(x) for x in parts[1].split()])
```

And it should work.